# what's handle and isa 

Tags: matlab

I need an explanation with a simple examples about the following concepts:

- 'handle' function
- `@`
- `+`
- `isa`

Comment: Did you even try to search the online documentation? [@ folder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfynrp-1.html), [+ folder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfynt_-1.html), [ISA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isa.html), [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html)

Comment: I do need to object that the + and @ are nearly impossible to find by search.

Comment: @bdecaf: Actually, they were very easy to find. I just Googled "matlab folders", clicked the very first link, and just a few lines down it mentions "@ (class) and + (package) folders". Then just click around on some links or search further with those terms.

Comment: Well when you know what they are about yes. First time I encountered them - try googling "matlab +"

Comment: @gnovice : I googled 'Matlab folders' and I don't found @,+,..etc . if I have asked the question, it means that I 've serached before but don't found a simple explanation.

Answer (score 2):

These are part of API that mathworks has devised.

1. A folder whose name begins with an @ sign contains the definition of Matlab objects.
2. The folders with the + sign are similar, but they are used to define a "package" or namespace.  These are hard to give an example of, but I would recommend looking at the help like gnovice says and looking through your matlab install folders for examples.
3. The `isa()` command takes an object and a string and tells you if the object is of the class descibed by the string.
4. A function handle, is just like a function pointer.  You can pass the function handle around if you assign the function to a variable like:

   `myFuncRef = @isempty`

Now you have a reference to the isempty() function which can be use like so:

```
myFuncRef(somevar)
```